# Timeline overflow screw up next elements

Tags: html, css

I am using [a library that create timeline](http://visjs.org/timeline_examples.html). This is javascript based.

I have the following html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    //Stuff here
  </div>
  <div class="row>
    <div id="timeline">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row>
    //Other stuff here
  </div>
</div>
```

And the timeline library is replacing my `$('#timeline')` element by the timeline

If I do not have many elements on my timeline, everything is fine
[image]

But if I have more elements, the timeline is expending through the third `<div class="row">`.
[image]

How to fix it to have the third row always placed after the timeline ?
I do not want to hide the overflow.
What CSS trick should I try ?

Comment: I don't think we can answer your question without your code.

Comment: try adding class clearfix if you are using something like that or any thing similar
I would be better if you post your css too

Comment: @AkashKOdesia It worked with the overflow:auto; The fact is that all the CSS is managed by the library (too much data for posting here). If you can answer instead of commenting I will approve yours

Comment: @Raccon Thanks mate just posted the in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding class clearfix if you are using something like that or any thing similar I would be better if you post your css too

Answer (score 0):

just for kicks, try....

if it doesnt work i will delete... but my understanding is that its worth a try.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    //Stuff here
  </div>
  <div class="row>
    <div id="timeline">
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div> <!--this is the added line-->
  </div>
  <div class="row>
    //Other stuff here
  </div>
</div>
```